# Read AMQ queue messages without creating a new queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to browse messages from ActiveMQ queue using the following code. This will create a new `destinationQueue` on the broker if one doesn't exists. How can I avoid creating a new queue? I was expecting a `JMSException` if the given queue doesn't exist.

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");       
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = session.createQueue(destinationQueue);
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
Enumeration enumMsgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-restrict-connections-from-creating-new-queues-or-topics.html) on this subject:

> As is described in [How do I create new destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html) there is no need to create all the destinations up front, you can let the broker create them on the fly.
>
> However if you don't want this behaviour, or wish to restrict this behaviour to certain topic or queue [Wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html) (areas of the queue or topic name space) then you can use the [Security](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html) plugins to disallow the **admin** role on whatever areas of the queue and topic namespace you wish

Answer (score 0):

Its a live system and unfortunately I have no access to its security settings or another user. But found a work around,
I fetched the collection of queues by the following code and validated the 'destinationQueue'[provided Queue name for browsing] with the collection before creating 'QueueBrowser'

```
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection)connectionFactory.createConnection("admin","admin");
        connection.start();
        DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
        Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();
        for (ActiveMQQueue queue : queues) {
            if (destinationQueue.equals(queue.getPhysicalName())) {
                queueExists = true;
            }

        }
```